# allow the user to update textbox value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

i am developing a project in ASP.NET MVC5 using SQL SERVER 2012

In this in one of the for i have scenario where user clicks on the Edit button and modal popup gets open with populated Email address in it(user can change it); after user changes the value of email that new email should gets stored.

my code is as below:

```
<tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <td>
    <input id="txtEmailId" name="txtEmailId"type="text" class="form-control"
     placeholder="Email" size="254" style="width: 200px;"
    value="@ViewBag.EmailAddress"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**js code is as below:**
      //save profile email address

```
$("#btnSaveProfile").click(function (e) {
   debugger;
//   var test = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
     var userEmail = $("#txtEmailId").val();
     alert(userEmail);
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/UserProfile/SaveUserDetails?EmailAddress=' + userEmail,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    alert("Email Saved")

                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error :" + msg.responseText);
            }
       });

})
```

but it is saving older email address.

Comment: You're using `$("txtEmail").val()` but in your example markup it doesn't exist - you've used `txtEmailId`, is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: In your HTML, the input has `txtEmailId` as its Id. In your code you're using `#txtEmail`. A typo?

Comment: @billyonecan  my mistake while copy pasting code form project

Comment: @user3480139 check the server side code that handles saving the e-mail address, is it receiving the value expected, and is it actually saving the record?

Comment: @ billyonecan i checked my controller function while debugging but it is receiving the older textbox value.

Comment: @billyonecan it is happening bacause i am setting textbox value in view value="@ViewBag.EmailAddress"

Comment: Is the $("#btnSaveProfile") the button in the modal pop-up? The button in the modal pop-up may need to trigger a script that assigns the new value to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referenceing the wrong input? Should you use:

```
$("#txtEmailId").val();
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but was copy pasting mistake from project.

Comment: Is it the fact that you are binding the value then?

value="@ViewBag.EmailAddress"

Comment: i have checked it i think it is happening because of this. but when modal pops up i need to show some values in textboxes; thats why i did that. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The button in the modal pop-up may need to trigger a script that assigns the new value to the input field $('#txtEmailId').

Sample html for modal pop-up.

```
<div class="modal-pop-up">
   <input type="text" id="new-email" name="new-email">
   <button id="save-btn">Assign New Email</button>
</div>
```

Sample script for modal pop-up.

```
$("#save-btn").on('click', function(e){
   var $newEmail = $('#new-email').val();
   $("#txtEmailId").val($newEmail);
   // close modal
});
```

However you may not really need a modal pop-up just to allow the user to modify a single field in the original form.

It seems you are not assigning the data property:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/UserProfile/SaveUserDetails?EmailAddress=' + userEmail,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { EmailAddress: userEmail } /* assign data property */
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    alert("Email Saved")

                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error :" + msg.responseText);
            }
       });
```